# Is there a nice formula for $\prod_{j=1}^n \phi(j)\ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I searched for prime numbers of the form $$(\prod_{j=1}^n \phi(j))+1$$ where $\phi(n)$ is the totient function. I wonder whether the function $$f(n):=\prod_{j=1}^n \phi(j)$$ has a nice closed form using factorials, lcm's or whatsoever.

For those who are interested : $f(n)+1$ is prime for the following positive integers $n\le 1000$ : $$[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 34, 43, 85, 162, 173, 538, 552]$$ Curious side-note : $f(43)+1$ is a $43$ digit-prime and $43$ is prime as well.

> Does a nice formula for $f(n)$ exist ?

Comment: Next values : $$1089\ 1268\ 1307$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an $n\times n$ matrix with $(i,j)$th entry as as $\gcd(i,j)$ the determinant is the product you mentioned.
This is found in the book by Niven and Zuckerman "Number Theory"

Comment: Nice answer (+1)